# Can't install flash on Firefox or Chrome (but works fine on IE...)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, flash

I'm using a work computer (Lenovo) that I recently got from my IT department to replace an old machine. When I installed Firefox and Chrome, I needed to install Adobe Flash. However, the installation has failed on several occasions. I've taken all the usual steps: closing all programs and windows, installing updates and restarting machine, etc, but still the installation does not work. The download manager and status bars say that installation is complete, but I still can't view flash sites on FF or Chrome. Flash is working fine on IE though. Last thing: when I reboot the first dialog box that comes up is from Adobe Download Manager, and it says "Please shut down Internet Explorer before uninstall can complete". I'm confused since a) I've just rebooted so have yet to start IE and b) why UNinstall?

My company does not support non-IE browsers so I'm not getting much help from our IT department.

If necessary I can post screenshots of error messages and stuff if it comes to that, but hopefully someone will be able to diagnose the problem before that's necessary as I'm not the most tech savvy (despite being a huge fan of reddit...)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try to uninstall flash player first [Flash uninstaller.](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/current/uninstall_flash_player.exe) , and then install it again [Select OS and then select browser](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/)
(Close all your opened browsers before uninstalling and installing as well).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are downloading the Flash package for non-IE browsers?

You may manually download the installation package for third-party browsers here:

> http://fpdownload.adobe.com/get/flashplayer/current/install_flash_player.exe

Please note that you need **administrator rights** on your computer to install this package on your computer. Without administrator rights, you will not be able to install Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Flash is integrated in Chrome, you do not need to install it. However, due to the push to end-of-life Flash (because of numerous security reasons too lengthy to go into here), Google and others are trying to get rid of it ASAP.

As such **it has been disabled by default in the latest build of Chrome. To enable it, simply type (or copy/paste) this into your Chrome address bar: `chrome://plugins` then go "Adobe Flash Player" and check the "always allowed" box.**

Comment: We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but please keep in mind that this question is more than *seven years* old.  There are many things that have changed within the default configurations of both Chrome and Firefox since early 2010.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't notice that! Thanks, I'll check the dates next time.